# Turn commandline input into an array

Tags: java, arrays, command-line

I'm working on a Bruce Eckel exercise on how to take a keyboard command line input and put it into an array. It's supposed to take 3 separate inputs and place them into an array and print them back out.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
//: object/PushtoArray
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; 
class PushtoArray { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String[] s = new String[3]; 
    int i = 0; 

    //initialize console 
    Console c = System.console();   

    while ( i <= 2 ) {
        //prompt entry:
        //System.out.println("Enter entry #" + i + ": ");  
        //readin 
            s[i] = c.readLine("enter entry #" + i + ": "); 

        //increment counter 
        i++;                

    } //end while 

    //reset counter 
    i = 0; 

    //print out array
    while ( i <= 2 ) { 
        System.out.println(s[i]);
            i++;
    } //end while 
    }//end main

} //end class
```

**UPDATE:** Now I get a different error:

```
PushtoArray.java:15: readline(boolean) in java.io.Console cannot be applied to (java.lang.string) 
      s[i]= c.readline("Enter entry #" + i + ": ");
```

I'm trying to read in from the command prompt but it isn't prompting at all.  It compiles correctly when I javac the java file.

Am I using the wrong function?  Should I be using a push method instead of an assignment?

Comment: Where does your readline method come from? Do you define it?

Comment: Does this code actually match what generates your error. The above error suggests that you're not finding your main method, and so is that correctly defined (it does appear so above)

Comment: @phill: Have you seen my second edit?

Comment: @mmyers yes i did.. thanks .. that got it to start prompting for input

Comment: You still need to change the condition in the last while loop to i <= 2. As it is now, it will get three strings from the user but will only print the first two.

Comment: @all - Thanks to everyone for the help and input, i finally got it to run. I learned alot from the exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you're running `javac` on the right file? There is no way that file could compile.

1. You need a semicolon on the import statement:

   ```
   import java.io.*;
   ```
2. You forgot an end brace:

   ```
   } // end main()
   ```
3. There is no such method as `readline()`. You need to read from `System.in`. The easiest way is to make a `Scanner` before the loop, then read from it in the loop. See the Javadocs for [`Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for an example.

**Edit:** See the [Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html) for more on reading from the command line. The [`Console` class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) (introduced in Java 6) looks like it has the `readLine()` method that you wanted.

**Edit 2:** You need to capitalize Line. You wrote "`readline`", but it should be "`readLine`".

Comment: What is this `javac` of which you speak? :P

Comment: thanks.. i made the corrections on the code.  I found the readline() method by going java.io > DataInput > string readline() method..  i guess this is incorrect..

Comment: Oh, oh... From that last comment, I'm thinking there are much deeper problems here.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

and then in your loop:

```
in.readline();
```

I would push the received lines into an ArrayList or similar. That way you can accept more/less than 3 lines of data (but that's only necessary if the number of lines you want to accept is variable)

EDIT: I thought originally the NoSuchMethod exception was highlighting a scoping problem. Obviously not, and thx to those who pointed that out!

Comment: could you please detail how you found this in the api?  Is there an easier search function on http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/?  is there an easier way than poking around the api until you find the function you need?

Comment: Ah. Experience, I'm afraid. Knowing that System.in is the input stream, and that you have to wrap it in a reader to convert to chars, and then BufferedReader delivers lines. You could start by searching for 'java readline'

Answer (score 1):

```
//print out array
    while ( i < 2 ) { 
        System.out.println(s[i]);
        i++; //increase counter!
    } //end while
```

Comment: Yes, logic errors are nastier than syntax errors. (A for-loop would be even better.)

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you are looking for, but it takes three command line arguments, stores them into an array, then prints out the arguments from the new array:

```
public class CommandArray {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        //Set up array to hold command line values
        String[] arr = new String[3];

        //Copy command line values into new array
        for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
            arr[i] = args[i];

        //Print command line values from new array
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");

            //Extra line for terminal
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Then, after you compile your code with `javac CommandArray.java`, you can execute it with `java CommandArray Arg1 Arg2 Arg3`.

Also, I noticed that, in your final while loop, you had:

```
while(i < 2) {
```

If the command line accepts 3 arguments, you would only print 2. The array indexes printed would be 0 and 1 since 1 < 2.  You can change it to say:

```
while(i <= 2) {
```

And don't forget to increment i.

Comment: good catch.. thanks for pointing out the conditional statement